# Replacing spaces with a letter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to Replace the spaces in a string i have with a "x" its for a function and im not sure of the best way to go about this ?

for example

`how is your day ?`

i would like this to be 
 `howxisxyourxdayx?`

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
string.replace(' ', 'x')
```

Comment: would you know how to reverse a string for example red turning into der?

Comment: @user2272942 Ask single questions here, don't use the comments for unrelated things, anyway for that `string[::-1]`. Please read the python tutorial

Comment: @user2272942 Sure, try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace()

```
text.replace(' ', 'x')
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that variable name, it's the same as python's builtin `str` for strings

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = 'how is your day ?'
>>> text.replace(' ', 'x')
'howxisxyourxdayx?'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use the regular expression module

```
import re

In [9]: re.sub(' ', 'x', text)
Out[9]: 'howxisxyourxdayx?'
```

Comment: regex should be the last idea that comes into your head